# Select element with specific properties d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am drawing a tree (somewhat similar to a decision tree) with D3.js, using a premade template I found online. My goal at this point is to color the edges (or `links`) according to a property of each `link` object.

My first step was to color all the edges regardless of their property, so I added the following line:

```
      // Update the links…
      var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(links, function(d) {
              return d.target.id;
          });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          //.style("stroke", "red")  ---- this new line changes the color of all links
          .attr("d", function(d) {
              var o = {
                  x: source.x0,
                  y: source.y0
              };
              return diagonal({
                  source: o,
                  target: o
              });
          });
```

Now, I want to color them according to their property. It is accessible through the first `link` initialization:

```
  // Update the links…
  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
          // const booleanProperty = d.target.colorProperty;  --- change color according to this property
          return d.target.id;
      });
```

My thought was to create 2 different variables - one storing the links with the property set to `true` and another with the property set to `false`, so I could change the color of each `link` group. Somewhat like this:

```
 // Update the links…
  var trueLink = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
          const booleanProperty = d.target.colorProperty;  --- change color according to this property
          if (booleanProperty) return d.target.id;
      });

  var falseLink = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
          const booleanProperty = d.target.colorProperty;  --- change color according to this property
          if (!booleanProperty) return d.target.id;
      });
```

This attempt didn't work, since `selectAll("path.link")` returns all the links regardless if there is a condition to return only in specific cases. I also tried using `select("path.link")`, but I got exactly the same result.

Is there a way I can pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to set that style in the "enter" selection for new items, so you could try to do the condition inside the .style call, something like this:

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return condition ? "red" : "blue"; } )
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
      });
  });
```

Where "condition" may be anything you need. If the condition or the color is stored in the datum, you can return d.target.colorProperty or use it for the condition.